# Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.io.IOError: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Invalid file path

Tags: java, spring-boot, jboss, redhat

I hope you can help me, I have a springboot application which starts on a redhat jboss eap 7.3 server (This is already a project in which I started to collaborate and in the others if it works for them). The server starts fine, the application is the same, but when I try to make a request through PostMan I get the following error:

```shell
ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-1) UT005023: Exception handling request to /proteccion/actuacion/1: org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.io.IOError: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Invalid file path.
```

**pom.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.5</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <groupId>co.gov.sic.proteccion</groupId>
    <artifactId>api-proteccion</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>api-proteccion</name>
    <description>Api Proteccion</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.docx4j/docx4j -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.docx4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>docx4j</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
    
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20210307</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi-ooxml -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
            <version>1.14</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Se evita el uso del tomcat -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ibm.informix</groupId>
            <artifactId>jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>4.50.4.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.awaitility</groupId>
            <artifactId>awaitility</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
            <version>1.15</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>proteccion</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

```shell
Error: 
09:18:06,637 INFO  [io.undertow.servlet] (default task-1) Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
09:18:06,637 INFO  [org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet] (default task-1) Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
09:18:06,641 INFO  [org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet] (default task-1) Completed initialization in 3 ms
09:18:06,728 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1) Hibernate: select actuacion0_.codi_actu as codi_act1_0_0_, actuacion0_.desc_actu as desc_act2_0_0_, actuacion0_.esta_actu as esta_act3_0_0_, actuacion0_.fech_crea as fech_cre4_0_0_, actuacion0_.fech_vige as fech_vig5_0_0_, actuacion0_.noab_actu as noab_act6_0_0_, actuacion0_.nomb_actu as nomb_act7_0_0_, actuacion0_.novi_actu as novi_act8_0_0_, actuacion0_.tipo_actu as tipo_act9_0_0_ from actuacion actuacion0_ where actuacion0_.codi_actu=?

09:18:09,561 ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-1) UT005023: Exception handling request to /proteccion/actuacion/1: org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.io.IOError: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Invalid file path
```

Comment: Is there a stack trace associated with the logged error?

Comment: like which one sorry?

Comment: Is there more than one stack trace?

Comment: like this? https://docs.google.com/document/d/1gJ4_L841Tz2_-dQOR9--1ivoXPm31zCUWNwVldSMMhU/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Yes. You'd want to look to see what the resource behind /proteccion/actuacion/1. It seems to be coming from Spring which I don't really know much about.

Comment: Sure, I've updated the document. https://docs.google.com/document/d/1gJ4_L841Tz2_-dQOR9--1ivoXPm31zCUWNwVldSMMhU/edit?usp=sharing